# passing data from Cordova to inAppBrowser

Tags: cordova, inappbrowser, phonegap-cli

I've found this tutorial to use localStorage to trigger an event inside phonegap/cordova: http://www.telerik.com/blogs/cross-window-communication-with-cordova's-inappbrowser

This works perfectly fine. I am using a click function inside the inAppBrowser to set a local storage item, which then opens the camera from the main phonegap view. Now I need to send the image data back when the image is captured, but I cannot find a way to set the localStorage item of the inAppBrowser from Phonegap/Cordova. I feel like I'm close but cannot figure it out... Can someone help?

Answer (score 2):

It actually works the exact same way that the tutorial linked above works. I just had a typo in my code...